# Why do valid objects show up as Nil using lldb? (Apple LLVM Compiler 3.1, Xcode 4.3.1)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nslog, lldb

I'm trying to debug through some funky UIView behavior and I keep running into the case where LLDB is absolutely useless and misleading. Let me show you what I mean:

```
NSLog(@"myView: %@", myView);

2012-04-20 15:24:57.070 myProj[35789:f803] myView: <MyView: 0x7cc7500; frame = (0 119; 768 885); layer = <CALayer: 0x7cc8030>>
```

But when I set a breakpoint at that exact moment and try to use the debugger, it returns nil:

```
(lldb) po myView
(MyView *) $552 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

I would try shifting to GCC 4.2 to see if it helps, but compiling under LLVM GCC 4.2 is not an option as this is an ARC project.

Of course, LLDB will work if I already know the correct address to query. But the link between symbol names and the addresses seems to be broken for some objects, though it works for most other objects.

```
(lldb) po self
(MyViewController *const) $51 = 0x07e92200 <MyViewController: 0x7e92200>
(lldb) po myView
(MyView *) $25 = 0x00000000 <nil>
2012-04-20 15:44:17.250 myProject[37551:f803] myView: <MyView: 0x7e8e240; frame = (0 119; 768 885); layer = <CALayer: 0x7ea2330>>
(lldb) po 0x7e8e240
(int) $50 = 132702784 <MyView: 0x7e8e240; frame = (0 119; 768 885); layer = <CALayer: 0x7ea2330>>
```

How can I fix this? I've even tried self->myView, which didn't work either.

Update: (It gets worse!)

I should add that myView is a class variable, not a property, in this example (where lldb associates it with nil).
If I make myView a class property and @synthesize it, lldb will obtain an incorrect but predictable value and it will associate the myView symbol with the most recently synthesized property BEFORE the @synthesize. So in my case the code looked like this:

```
@synthesize myDate=myDate_;
@synthesize myView;
```

So when evaluating the property for myView from LLDB, it shows the date stored in myDate_:

```
(lldb) po myView
(MyView *) $24 = 0x07ca0900 2008-01-08 05:00:00 +0000
```

In the last case, if I make myView a method variable, LLDB will be correct:

```
(lldb) po myView
(UIView *) $7 = 0x07d81080 <MyView: 0x7d81080; frame = (0 119; 768 885); layer = <CALayer: 0x7d81b70>>
```

This smells like a very obvious bug in LLDB itself.

Update 2:

Further research: It looks like ALL of the class properties are wrong! The first property in the list shows a value of nil in LLDB, and all others show the value of the one synthesized right before it.

Could this be a weird config error?

Comment: BTW, you don't have to recompile your app with the gcc frontend just to use gdb. If you want to use gdb, just change the debugger for your scheme to gdb. You can continue to compile with LLVM3 and ARC.

Comment: if myView is a property, have you tried just accessing the property itself: `po [self myView]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be: avoid testing in the simulator when trying to use the debugger. Once I started testing on the device, all craziness went away and it started worked as expected. If I went back to the simulator I saw the same bugs again. Properties and method variables seemed to both have issues in the simulator.

Comment: glad to hear you got it fixed! :)

Comment: Update on this: lldb on Xcode 4.3.1 had a bug when using the simulator. 

I filed a radar on this and Apple fixed in 4.4.1. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW163

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your Build Configuration is set to Debug and not AdHoc, Release, or something else that strips out debug symbols or disallows debugging in the entitlements file.

This just bit me because I forgot to switch the configuration back to Debug after creating an ad hoc build for my device. Strangely, most of the app worked, but certain stack frames would fail silently and inexplicably, with all variables (including `self`) either nil or mangled.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame variable -o myView
```

[More here](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) under 'EXAMINING STACK FRAME STATE' heading.

Comment: (lldb) frame variable myView  
error: no variable named 'myView' found in this frame

Comment: The -O parameter works similarly:

    (lldb) frame variable -O myView
    error: no variable named 'myView' found in this frame

Comment: So I realized I was testing against the Simulator for speed, and did testing against the device. LLDB started working perfectly.

Tested against the simulator again: broken again.
Tested against the device: fixed again.

So I guess the moral of the story is that LLDB might have unfixed bugs with the simulator.

Comment: @AlleyGator file a bug report here with your test findings: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Apple's bug reporter is broken. As usual.

Comment: @AlleyGator maybe they should attach to it with LLDB ;)